# My chat consumer is not working django-channels?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am tryna make a one-one chat application but my chat socket get's disconnected immediately when i send the data to it.I think the problem is in my asynchronous recieve function of my consumer?
It's not giving me any reason for the error?The socket disconnects silently

Here's the recieve handler

```
async def receive(self, text_data):
    data = json.loads(text_data)
    text = data['message']
    room_name = data['room_name']
    username   = data["username"]
    only_one_user = False
    profile       = self.scope["user"].profile

    # GET THE ROOM AND THE PROFILE
    room_obj    = await database_sync_to_async(Room.objects.get)(pk=self.room_name)
    other_user  = await database_sync_to_async(room_obj.other_user)(profile)

    # CREATE AND ADD THE MESSAGE TO THE ROOM
    message = Message.objects.create(author=profile,text=text,to=other_user.user.username)
    room_obj.messages.add(message)
    room_obj.updated  = timezone.now()
    room_obj.save()
    profile = self.scope["user"].profile
    clients_connected = await database_sync_to_async(Websocketclient.objects.filter)(room=int(self.room_name))


    if clients_connected.count() < 2:
        only_one_user = True                

    # Send message to room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.room_group_name,
        {

            'type': 'chat_message',
            'data': {"text":text,"pk":room_obj.pk,"author":{"username":message.author.user.username,"image":str(message.author.image)},"only_one_user":only_one_user}
        }
    )
```

Also how can i know what exactly is the error in my async code if i get any in future work...

Comment: Message.objects.create should also be wrapped in `database_sync_to_async` and `room_obj.save()` any DB operation needs to be wrapped in `database_sync_to_async`.

as to why the error is be swallowed... welcome to async python :) put a try except around the body of your function and print out the exception you get to test that the error is a this point.

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Message.objects.create` should also be wrapped in `database_sync_to_async` and `room_obj.save()`

in short any DB operation needs to be wrapped in `database_sync_to_async`.

As to why the error is be swallowed... welcome to async python :)

put a try except around the body of your function and print out the exception you get to test that the error is a this point.